# how to rewrite this url with nginx

Tags: nginx

i have try to rewrite this url  in nginx server

from

`http://www.example.com/vb/?f=118&page=8`

to

`http://www.example.com/vb/forumdisplay.php?f=118&page=8`

but its not working with me

I use this

`rewrite ^/vb/(.*)f=(.*) /vb/forumdisplay.php?f=$2 permanent;`

my nginx server config is

```
server {
        listen *:80;
        server_name     www.gem-flash.com;
        rewrite_log on;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/a.gem-flash.com.log error;
        root   /home/gemnew/public_html/;
        error_page 404 /404.shtml;
        rewrite ^/vb/archive/index.php/t-([0-9]+)\.html /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/vb/archive/index.php/f-([0-9]+)\.html /vb/forumdisplay.php?f=$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/vb/archive/index.php/f-([0-9]+)-p-([0-9]+)\.html /vb/forumdisplay.php?f=$1&page=$2 permanent;
        rewrite ^/vb/archive/index.php/t-([0-9]+)-p-([0-9]+)\.html /vb/showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 permanent;
        rewrite ^/vb/showthread.php?t=([0-9]+)&langid=1 /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/~gemflash/vb(.*) /vb$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/vb/vb/(.*) /vb/$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/vbtest/(.*) /vb/$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/vb/forum.php /vb/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/vb/(.*)f=(.*) /vb/forumdisplay.php?f=$2 permanent;
        rewrite ^/index.html /vb/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/vb/((urllist|sitemap).*.(xml|txt)(.gz)?)$ /vb/vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap=$1 last;
        error_page 404 /404.shtml;
        location  /404.shtml {
        internal;
}
```

Comment: What's reason for that? May be simple `index forumdisplay.php;` will help?

Comment: index is diff from forumdisplay.php . and google webmaster notice that I have duplicate links with same content and same title . so I need to rewrite one of them to other to be one link only

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this rewrite URL in my own NGINX configuration and i ended up with the following line:

```
rewrite ^/vb/?f=(.*) /vb/forumdisplay.php?f=$1 permanent;
```

Can you give it some testing?

Thijs

Comment: I think the problem in ? in the rules